# How can I allocate space on my hard drive for ubuntu install?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Okay so I just use a flash drive and put the iso file on that. Then I go to the bios and arrange it to boot from the flash drive and then I can use the test version of ubuntu but when I try to install it says I dont have enough space (only 4gb of 8.6gb required). How can I put space on my hard drive for the install and other things rather than having it use the flash drive.

Sorry english is not my first language

I am on windows 10

Comment: From terminal in live installer in live mode post this above to preserve formatting: `sudo parted -l` That is an el, not 1 nor capital i.  Best to copy  & paste.

Comment: It's probably not recognizing your hard disk, and it's trying to install on the flash drive. In the BIOS, what is the hard disk type set to? RAID, IDE, SCSI, SATA or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you still have windows on it. resizing windows partitions is best done from within windows.

go to the control panel --> administrative tools ---> drive management

there you can shrink your partition enough to put ubuntu on the freed space

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install parallel OS, Installing a parallel OS needs some empty disk unformated minimum of 16 GB or more for Ubuntu, or wipeout entire drive and just install ubuntu, which will be a clean install